# how to change size dropdown arrow icon?

Tags: html, css

how to change the size of the drop down icon? it is possible in css? thanks if not i i want to replace it to image btn.. thanks!

```html
<select>
    <option value="age">18</option>
    <option value="age">19</option>
    <option value="age">20</option>
    <option value="age">21</option>
    <option value="age">22</option>
    <option value="age">23</option>
    <option value="age">24</option>
    <option value="age">25</option>
    <option value="age">26</option>
    <option value="age">27</option>
    <option value="age">28</option>
    <option value="age">29</option>
    <option value="age">30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow Does this help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace select dropdown arrow with fa-icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990575/replace-select-dropdown-arrow-with-fa-icon)

Answer (score 0):

use below css for your select:

```
.select {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-position-x: 244px;
}
```