# bootstrap-select library using font-awsome for dropdown icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

i am using bootstrap-select for a search UI i am doing, everything is working fine and the library comes with alot of good options. I want to replace the default dropdown icon to my font awsome icon, this way i can control the styles of the icon. i have tried their default way of icon change , which is not working , what i am i doing wrong here.

default icon
[image]

desired icon
[image]

here is icon changing function i tried with no luck

```
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        iconBase: 'fa',
        tickIcon: 'fa-chevron-down',
     });
```

Is there a css way of doing this ? if there a working function like above , that would be better.

**Here is my work so far**

```css
.dnow-searchWizard-wrap .dropdown.bootstrap-select button.btn-light {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.dnow-searchWizard-wrap .btn-primary {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

   <section class="dnow-searchWizard-wrap bg-light p-5">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
               <h2>H2 Find Solutions That Work for You</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 align-self-center">
               <p><strong>I AM LOOKING FOR</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="selectpicker form-control">
                     <optgroup label="Picnic">
                        <option>Mustard</option>
                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                     </optgroup>
                     <optgroup label="Camping">
                        <option>Tent</option>
                        <option>Flashlight</option>
                        <option>Toilet Paper</option>
                     </optgroup>
                  </select>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 align-self-center text-center">
               <p><strong>IN</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="selectpicker form-control">
                     <optgroup label="Picnic">
                        <option>Mustard</option>
                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                     </optgroup>
                     <optgroup label="Camping">
                        <option>Tent</option>
                        <option>Flashlight</option>
                        <option>Toilet Paper</option>
                     </optgroup>
                  </select>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               <button class="btn btn-primary">Show My Results</button>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>
   </section>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

   <!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            iconBase: 'fa',
            tickIcon: 'fa-check',
         });
      });

   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you try this approach instead maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833573/how-to-change-bootstrap-select-arrows-to-glyphicon

Comment: There's also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990787/8437694

Comment: since its not a regular bootstrap select , the library adds bunch of wraps around it, above solutions doesn't fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap 4 adds its dropdown icon using the border trick, So after adding my own icon using dropdown ::after, I had to override all border to none to remove the default icon. You can do the same for the drop up.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    /* display: inline-block; */
    content: '\f123';
    /* width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 0.255em;
    vertical-align: 0.255em; */
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.dropup .dropdown-toggle::after {
    /*display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .255em;
    vertical-align: .255em;*/
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    content: "\f126";
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with a vector image using the css below. It would also be possible to do it with a ':after" and using the 'content' styling but I haven't tried that. If nobody else helps, I at least gave you one solution that will work.

```
.changedSelect {
    padding: 0 32px 0 5px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../DropDownArrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 5px center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}

/*Hide the original drop down arrow on internet explorer*/
.changedSelect::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
};
```

UPDATE: So being the amazing person that I am, browsers do not allow you to add a font awesome icon using the :after and content CSS on a select, which means as far as I am aware, the solution I posted would be the only way to add a custom arrow, unless you add a wrapper. It is possible to add Font Awesome icons to normal divs using before and after as per the comment that was added from IvanS

Comment: Actually you can use FontAwesome and other icons in `::after` using `content` if you use their css Character Entities, for example for the icon requeste it would be `\f078`, but you also have to include its font family

Comment: I tired that. It works fine on normal DIVs but not the SELECT.